# how to add date while importing data in csv from mysql query

Tags: mysql

need to add date in the file name into outfile caluse below pease suggest

```
SET @outpath = "/var/lib/mysql-files/";
SET @outfile = (SELECT NOW());
SET @outextension = "_StepCount.csv";
SET @SQL := CONCAT("Select Concat(ifnull(First_Name,'')," ",ifnull(Middle_Name,'')," ",ifnull(Last_name,'')) AS Name, u.email from users",@outpath,@outfile,@outextension ) ;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use char(39) (single quote)

```
SET @SQL := CONCAT("Select Concat(ifnull(First_Name,'')," ",ifnull(Middle_Name,'')," ",ifnull(Last_name,'')) AS Name, u.email from users",
CHAR(39),@outpath,@outfile,@outextension,CHAR(39) ) ;
```

NB- I haven't corrected the other errors in this code but if you select @sql they should be obvious.

Comment: Hi Thanks , but getting error as follows - 

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',ifnull(Middle_Name,''),,ifnull(Last_name,'')) AS Name, email from users'/var/li' at line 1

```
Please advise

Comment: Remove the double commas , insert space between users and file name etc..